# How to calculate rotation needed to face an object

Tags: c#, math, rotation, point

In case of duplicate - i already readed other posts from stackoverflow. Most of them are asociated with Unity3D, and a lot of them are using keywords like theta/omega .. ect. I can't understand any of that stuff. Also, i have 0 knowledge of those formula symbols so i understand 0% of what i readed.

I experiment making a bot for a video game, the only thing im stuck with is how to get the needed rotation degree till i face the given cordinate. Here i made quick example of my question in programming.

Things that i know in the situation:

1. Player1 position
2. Player1 rotation
3. Player2 position (i need to face this player)

[2D map of the situation. Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa0TD.png)

And here is how it looks in c#

```html
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    // Player 1 cordinates
    public static float p1x = 2;
    public static float p1y = 3;
    public static float p1rotation = 0; // In degrees 0-360
    
    // Player 2 cordinates
    public static float p2x = 6;
    public static float p2y = 4;
    
    // Player 1 needed degree to face Player 2
    public static float needed_distance;
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        needed_distance = ??; // no clue how to get this value ...
        Console.WriteLine("The needed distance is: "+needed_distance);
        
    }
}
```

Also you can edit this code and execute it here directly -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/b4PTcw

Please don't mark this as a duplicate, my math skills are even below zero. I can understand better if someone tries to answer me using the example that i made.

Comment: you are after the rotation or the distance?

Comment: rotation, i already have script for the distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Math.Atan2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan2?view=net-6.0) method:

```
private static float Rotation(float p1x, float p1y, float p2x, float p2y) =>
  (float)(Math.Atan2(p1x - p2x, p2y - p1y) * 180.0 / Math.PI + 630) % 360.0f;

private static float Distance(float p1x, float p1y, float p2x, float p2y) =>
  (float)Math.Sqrt((p1x - p2x) * (p1x - p2x) + (p1y - p2y) * (p1y - p2y));
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.WriteLine(Rotation(2, 3, 6, 4));
```

**Outcome:**

```
194.0362548828125
```

So, if player #1 initial `rotation1 = 0` (s)he needs to turn at ~ `194` degree. In case of player #1 *arbitrary* initial `rotation1`:

```
float rotation1 = ...;

float requiredRotation = (Rotation(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y) - 
   (rotation1 % 360f) + 360f) % 360f;
```

Comment: I used the Atan2 method for 2 days until i got pissed. When i rotate my player the calculated angle doesn't seem to change. Maybe i forgot to mention that my player is a 3D object. So, my player's rotation angle is something separate from its global angle towards the player2. Can you help me with this pls ?

Comment: What is mean is this. My player has known
Cordinates (x: 2, y: ?? z: 3) (for z i use the namespace y for atan2)
Rotations (x: ??, y: 0, z: ??) PLEASE can you help me with this im begging you

Comment: @VictorTheBeast: first of all, let's *define the problem*. In the inital problem I can't see any `z` coordinate and angle definition (what angle we are looking for). You put question mark for player #1 `y` and for both `x` and `z` player #2. What dot they mean, please? I've solved the problem based on your sketch. Please redraw it if it's incorrect

Comment: @VictorTheBeast: or may be you'll want to set yet another **3d** (space) problem where both players have `x, y, z` coordinate and you are looking for a specific angle?

Comment: Well, with your method i was able to find the global angle from the 2 players. So i got the player1 running around in circle outside player2 and the value changes 0-360, yeah it works. But in 3d space it is different because the character has a local orientation and i have its value converted to degrees also. So, using your method i got the global orientation. How can i apply it to my local orientation? I got the local orientation and its even converted in degress, so can i find how many degrees i got left till i face the target using the global orientation that u already helped me achieve?

Comment: @VictorTheBeast: usually, when working with **3d** we use **3** standard angles: **roll**, ""pitch"" and **yaw**. If you are looking for some other single angle, please open a new question and draw a sketch with this angle